# Testing a button which renders ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

the problem is I am trying to write test for a button which rendered ajax in views,but it always shows cannot find the button or link(which means neither click_button nor click_link works),or say the format is wrong. What shall I change in my code to make the test pass? Thank you for your help. 
My test code is show below:

```
describe 'Activate user'do
specify 'Admin logged in', :js => true  do
  admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
  user = User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', company: 'Genesys', position: 'Manager',role: 'member', access_token: '', email: 'user1@example.co.uk', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', active: false)
  login_as admin
  visit '/'
  visit "/controlpanel"
  click_link("user-freeze-btn-#{user.id}")
  expect(user.active).to eq(true)
end
end
```

and this is the code in the view which is a button rendering ajax:

```
= render :partial => 'user_freeze_btn', :locals => {:text => (user.active ? 'Activated' : 'Frozen'), :user => user, :btn_class => (user.active ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger')}
```

Here are the ajax "_user_freeze_btn.html.haml":

```
%td= link_to text, {:remote => true, :controller => :users, :action => :toggle, :id => user}, {:class => "btn #{btn_class} btn-sm user-freeze-btn", :id => "user-toggle-btn-#{user.id}"}
```

and "_user_freeze_btn.jason.haml":

```
%td= link_to text, {:remote => true, :controller => :users, :action => :toggle, :id => user}, {:class => "btn #{btn_class} btn-sm user-freeze-btn", :id => "user-toggle-btn-#{user.id}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`click_link` method finds a link by id, text or title. If you want to find a link by its id try adding `#`:

```
click_link("#user-freeze-btn-#{user.id}")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It doesn't work with adding a #, still shows cannot find the button nor link.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `save_and_open_screenshot` https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging To see what is happening on the page